# SD card reader not detected on Asus Zenbook, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, asus, sd-card, card-reader

I am trying to get my internal SD Card reader working on Ubuntu. I have only found a general solution and that was to reboot the computer with an SD Card inserted, which didn't work. I'm thinking it is either a driver issue or a formatting issue both, hopefully, with a pretty simple fix, but I'm not sure where I should be looking. Typing `lsusb` in the terminal brings up this:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0747 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0eef:7926 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b3fc Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Typing `df -h` in the terminal brings up this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       109G   35G   69G  34% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           787M  1.5M  786M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G  156K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
```

My computer is an Asus Zenbook UX31LA-US51T running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Note**: The SD Card I am trying to use has Raspberry Pi's Raspbian setup on it. I was looking to format the card before I got to this problem.

`lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0a03] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP Thermal [8086:9c24] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
```

Comment: Can you also [update](http://askubuntu.com/posts/663992/edit) your question with `lspci -nn` command output, please?

Comment: I updated it...